# Bars of bar graph in core plot is not click able if there is no value for bar graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I have a problem in core plot. There is delegate method when user taps on the bar which is given below.

```
- (void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
```

Which works fine when there is value for bar.It does not get call when there is no value for a bar. Is there is any way to make x-axis points click able for those bar which does not have value?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a delegate to the plot area, too. Implement the `-plotAreaWasSelected:` method and it will be called when the user touches the plot area outside the plot bars. If you need to know where the user touched, implement the `-plotAreaWasSelected:withEvent:` method instead and use the plot space to get the touch point from the event.

Comment: ok i hav one concern after implementing this delegate method how will i know which bar is selected i have to get the index of the graph which user will select.

Comment: Call `-dataIndexFromInteractionPoint:` on the plot for each point to get the data index. This will tell you which bar was touched. You can also use the `-plotPoint:numberOfCoordinates:forEvent:` or `-doublePrecisionPlotPoint:numberOfCoordinates:forEvent:` plot space methods to get the data coordinates of the touch points even if they're outside the bars.